# Is there a recurrence formula for finding primitive polynomials in order to construct $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

(In a previous question, I asked some related question but it was very disorientingly formulated. I apologize for that.)

Let $p$ be a prime and $n\geq 1$ an integer. The finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ with $p^n$ elements may be defined (up to isomorphism) as the splitting field of the polynomial $X^{p^n}-X\in\mathbb{F}_p[X]$.

I want to find for each $p$ and $n$ an irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ such that $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(f)=\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Such a polynomial exists, for example by the primitive element theorem as $\mathbb{F}_p$ is perfect. Such a polynomial $f$ is called a [primitive polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_%28field_theory%29).

> Is there a recurrence relation, like for [cyclotomic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), which gives such a primitive polynomial $f$ for given $p$ and $n$? (Or do I have to work for each $p$ and $n$ individually and try find some irreducible polynomial of degree $n$? If yes, what's the 'easiest' way to do it practically?)

Comment: Unless there is a way to distinguish a unique irreducible out of all the ones of degree $n$, uniformly across all $n$, I doubt there will be any kind of recursion closely resembling the one in characteristic zero. If one follows through with the same inclusion-exclusion argument, one gets that $\prod_{d\mid n}(T^{q^d}-T)^{\mu(n/d)}$ equals the product of all monic irreducibles in $\Bbb F_{q}[T]$ of degree $n$. One can factor this as a product of $\Phi_{\ell}(T)$ for all $\ell\mid(q^n-1)$ such that $q$ has multiplicative order $n$ mod $\ell$, which sorta reduces the problem a bit.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that no such formula is known. The problem is that cyclotomic polynomials split further over the prime field of characteristic $p$. A lot further.